# Why are seeds connected in Linear Congruential Generators?

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generators, random-number-generator

I looked through `Java`'s `Random` class and saw that the initial seed is created using:

```
public Random() {
        this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
    }
```

But every consecutive seed is derived from old seed using:`nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;`

Why is that? Why not use system time everytime?

Answer (score 1):

The first time your program asks for the system time, it's more or less random. Specifically, if the clock really does have nanosecond resolution, then the lowest-order 30 bits or so are truly unpredictable.

The second time your program asks for the system time, your deterministic program receives a number that is quite predictable if you already had the first result. Say the second call happens a millisecond, plus or minus a microsecond, later. There is a certain amount of jitter in the system, but you would be lucky if you obtained about 10 bits of additional entropy from this second call.

And this is assuming that your system clock really does have nanosecond precision, which may not be true. Remember, Java was designed to run on much lower-speed CPUs (e.g. microcontrollers and smartcards) than you are probably programming on.

Comment: I didnt understand what you said. Are you saying that if random numbers are requested fast then they will be sequential and predictable, if system time is used every time i.e. the numbers wont be spread out ? If that is the case, why not put the system to sleep for 0-10 ms (random based on last digit of system time or something) between random number requests?

Comment: @Vishal: people commonly use RNGs to generate billion numbers. Using a sleep would be criminal (not counting that it will not solve the non-independency problem).

Comment: Putting the system to sleep for a fixed time based on the previous system time seems... well, like an overly-complicated and artificially-delayed way to generate pseudo-random numbers based on one seed.